# Значение поля

Tags: jquery

```
<input class='nc_msvalues' type='hidden' name='good[30][name]' value='xxx'>
```

где 30 любое число может быть.

```
alert( $('input[@name="good[*][name]"]').val() );
```

Пытаюсь так, не получается...  Как получить значение value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо получить всезначения инпутов? Тогда можно ориентироваться по первой части атрибута **name** (как я понял, эта часть у вас постоянная)

```
$('input[name^="good"]').val()
```

**UPD:** В этом случае, вам надо [использовать плагинчик](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/), который позволит в селекторах использовать регулярные выражения

Comment: Но полей с good много.. важен третий элемен именно поле с [name]
НО на странице есть и поле просто с именем name

Comment: Дополнил в ответе